# How can I use Drupal Services from Flash via AMFPHP (AS3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drupal, amfphp

What libraries or sample code will show me how to invoke Drupal services over AMFPHP from ActionScript?  Ideally, they should be compatible with Flash, not just Flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DrupalSite](http://thirdavedesign.com/drupalsite/) is working great for me!